# I'm trying to make as so, on trigger, the player stops moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, rigid-bodies, topdown

I'm developing a TopDown 2D game in Unity.
The idea is, when the player steps on a certain tile, a UI with text pops up (already working) and the player stops moving until the player clicks a button (already programmed and working) and the UI disappears.
I was advised to turn the RigidBody2D to kinematic however it doesn't work and it just does what it used to do.
Am I doing something wrong?
Here is the code for the trigger script on the tiles:

```
public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string popUp;
    public void Start()
    {
 
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Rigidbody2D Player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            pop.PopUp(popUp);
            Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
        }

    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Rigidbody2D Player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        pop.closeBox();
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the popup keeps popping up instead of just popping up one time and then not again if you step on the tile again?

Comment: Since everything worked before you turned the RigidBody2D to kinematic, why is it an error if it is doing what it was used to do?

Comment: the pop up just pops up one time already, that's fixed.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it was advised to me on how to make the player to stop to turn the rigidbody to kinematic

Comment: @Lyxodius I've been testing without walking and it works as I want but the problem is just if u press WASD or the arrow keys, the player walks

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira disable the script that is handling the WASD input?

Comment: Instead of setting the plazer's Rigidbody to kinematic, you should have a flag that is checked when processing the WSAD input. Set that flag to false instead of setting the Rigidbody to kinematic.

Comment: @derHugo How do I do that? I'm new to Unity so I don't really know how to do things here xD

Comment: OK, im going to give it a try. I think we can stop the player by using a flag as I told before. Let me try.

Comment: @Hefaz I don't know how to make flags and stuff.

Comment: Ok, I have finished it. it works now. Just let me make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PopUpSystem.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PopUpSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject popUpBox;
    public Animator popupanimation;
    public TMP_Text popUpText;
    public PLayerController mb;
    public void PopUp(string text)
    {                
        popUpBox.SetActive(true);
        popUpText.text = text;
        popupanimation.SetTrigger("pop");         
    }

    public void closeBox()
    {
        popupanimation.SetTrigger("close");
        mb.camMove = true;
    }
}
```

PLayerController.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PLayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D MyRB;
    private Animator myAnim;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;
    public bool camMove = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        MyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (camMove)
        {
            MyRB.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            myAnim.SetFloat("moveX", MyRB.velocity.x);
            myAnim.SetFloat("moveY", MyRB.velocity.y);
            if ((Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 1) || (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == -1) || (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 1) || (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == -1))
            {
                myAnim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
                myAnim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
            }
        }

        if (!camMove)
        {
            MyRB.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

    }
    
}
```

TriggerScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string popUp;
    Animator popAnim;
    public PLayerController mb;

    private void Start()
    {
        popAnim = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PopUpBox").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        var myp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PLayerController>();
        
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            pop.PopUp(popUp);
            mb.camMove = false;
        }

        if (popAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).IsName("close"))
        {
            mb.camMove = true;
            Debug.Log("close");
        }


    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        pop.closeBox();
    }
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

1- Make a new tag and call it PopUpBox. then assign this tag to the Trigger GameObject.

2- To the button of the PopUpBox GameObject (the one which is disabled) assign GameManager GameObject and in its function select PopUpSystem.closeBox

3- In both Trigger GameObject and GameManager assign Player in Mb field.

Hope this help you. You can play with that more to get better results.

Comment: I'm having troubles with the second step. I assigned the button of the PopUpBox with the gameManager tag already but I don't see where I can select PopUpSystem.closeBox

Comment: Do not assign that tag to the button. it is useless. Just drag and drop GameManager GameObject to the button field as shown in the image and then select PopUpSystem.closeBox

Comment: ohhhhh thx xD I thought it was that but I wasn't sure