# How do i make it so my character/camera stops moving when UI is open?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just need to add to it to make the character movement/camera stop moving when the UI is open for the quest, but I don't get where to put the code for the bool variable. And then put to write for the code.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestGiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Quest quest;

    public GameObject questWindow;
    public Text titleText;
    public Text descriptionText;

    public Movement2 player;

    public void OpenQuestWindow()
    {
        questWindow.SetActive(true);
        titleText.text = quest.title;
        descriptionText.text = quest.description;
    }

    public void AcceptQuest()
    {
        questWindow.SetActive(false);
        quest.isActive = true;
        player.quest = quest;
    }
    
    void Start()
    {
        questWindow = GameObject.Find("QuestWindow");
        questWindow.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    public float playerSpeed = 5.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 40f;
    public float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    public Transform Cam;

    public KeyCode jump;
    public KeyCode FlyUp;
    public KeyCode FlyDown;
    public bool ablefly;

    private float  FlyMax = 250f;

    public Quest quest;
    public int SoulHP = 30;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        // add character controller
        // controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // check if the player is grounded and the vector3.y < 0, if one of this condition is true set back the playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector3 flyup = new Vector3(0, 50, 0);
        Vector3 flydown = new Vector3(0, -50, 0);
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        // Look for the camera y Rotation and multiply it for the vector 3 move in order make the player direction y as same as the camera.
        Vector3 FollowCam = Quaternion.Euler(0, Cam.eulerAngles.y, 0) * move;

        controller.Move(FollowCam * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        // makes the player jump by adding a float value to the vector 3 y 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(jump) && ablefly == false && groundedPlayer == true)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += 4f;
            //print("Diocane"); 
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(FlyUp) && ablefly == true)
        {
            //flyup = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(flyup, 250f);
            gravityValue = 0;
            controller.Move(flyup * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(FlyDown) && ablefly == true)
        {
            //flyup = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(flyup, 250f);
            gravityValue = 0;
            controller.Move(flydown * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
            
        }
       
        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);  
    }

    public void GoFind()
    {
        if (quest.isActive)
        {
            quest.goal.ItemCollected();
            if (quest.goal.IsReached())
                SoulHP += 30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `Time.timeScale` to 0 when the ui is opened to make anything using `deltaTime` stop moving.

In the `OpenQuestWindow()` you would add `Time.timeScale = 0;`
and in the `AcceptQuest()` method add `Time.timeScale = 1;` to set it back to normal

Comment: Hi, so I added it to the methods, however it's still not freezing my camera movement and my character movement, nothing changed. Does it matter at all where in the methods I put those two in? Because I tried at the top and the bottom of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265022/im-trying-to-make-as-so-on-trigger-the-player-stops-moving/66267448#66267448) question. please check this and ask me if you don't get that.

EDIT:

This is not a tested code, but I hope will give you an idea, of how to proceed.

1- define a public bool variable mybool in Movement2 script

2- call that bool in the QuestGiver Script like this:

```
void Start() {
  questWindow = GameObject.Find("QuestWindow");
  questWindow.SetActive(false);
  player.mybool = false; // or get the player gameobject by tag...
}
```

update your Movement2 update function to this:

```
void Update() {
  if (mybool) {
    // check if the player is grounded and the vector3.y < 0, if one of this condition is true set back the playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0) {
      playerVelocity.y = 0 f;
    }

    Vector3 flyup = new Vector3(0, 50, 0);
    Vector3 flydown = new Vector3(0, -50, 0);
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    // Look for the camera y Rotation and multiply it for the vector 3 move in order make the player direction y as same as the camera.
    Vector3 FollowCam = Quaternion.Euler(0, Cam.eulerAngles.y, 0) * move;

    controller.Move(FollowCam * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    // makes the player jump by adding a float value to the vector 3 y 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(jump) && ablefly == false && groundedPlayer == true) {
      playerVelocity.y += 4 f;
      //print("Diocane"); 
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(FlyUp) && ablefly == true) {
      //flyup = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(flyup, 250f);
      gravityValue = 0;
      controller.Move(flyup * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(FlyDown) && ablefly == true) {
      //flyup = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(flyup, 250f);
      gravityValue = 0;
      controller.Move(flydown * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
  }
  if (!camMove) {
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

  }
}
```

Now update that bool in QuestGiver:

```
public void OpenQuestWindow()
{
    questWindow.SetActive(true);
    titleText.text = quest.title;
    descriptionText.text = quest.description;
    player.mybool = false;
}

public void AcceptQuest()
{
    questWindow.SetActive(false);
    quest.isActive = true;
    player.quest = quest;
    player.mybool = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I tried adding the parts from that code you linked, to mine, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Movement script: https://hatebin.com/cykwfzgakd


Questgiver script: https://hatebin.com/tgafrmynzi


I followed your instructions to the best of my knowledge, and get these errors: https://i.imgur.com/T5CRJuQ.png


Sorry I'm new to coding, could you help me with this please.

Comment: you dont have the `if (!cantMove) { Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);}` at the end of the Update method in Movement2 and also remove the `player.cantMove = false;` from the start method of the QuestGiver script.